# Encryption and decryption

Tags: number-theory

Find the encryption and decryption transformations that are used in a system where the texts are encrypted by first applying the transformation $C = \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 1 \\
        3 & 7  \\
        \end{pmatrix}P (\mod 27 ) $ 
and then the transformation 
$C = \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 11 \\
        10 & 9  \\
        \end{pmatrix} P (\mod 27) $.

I took $P =\begin{pmatrix}
        x  \\
        y  \\
        \end{pmatrix}  $
and $C =\begin{pmatrix}
        a \\
        b  \\
        \end{pmatrix}  $

so $a \equiv 4x + y \\ b \equiv 3x+7y$ and  other way, $a \equiv 2x + 11y \\ b \equiv 10x + 9y$

But I don't have an idea how I can do it the exercise. 
The result is: $C =\begin{pmatrix}
        14 & 25 \\
        13 & 19  \\
        \end{pmatrix} P (\mod 27)  $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A(Bx)=(AB)x,$$

hence

\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 11 \\
        10 & 9  \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 1 \\
        3 & 7  \\
        \end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix} 8+33 & 2+77 \\40+27 & 10+63\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \begin{pmatrix} 8+6 & 2+2(27)+23 \\13+2(27) & 10+2(27)+9 \end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix}  14 & 25 \\13 & 19\end{pmatrix}\end{align}

where all computations are done in $\mod 27$.

Comment: What happend with 2 in $A_{12}$ ?

Comment: That was a typo, thanks, it should be there.